# How to update a key in a dictionary without overwriting the old value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
input = { "a" : { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
     "b" : { "x": 3, "z": 4 } }
output = {'y': {'a': 2},
                'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
                'z': {'b': 4} }
```

I need to make a new dictionary given the input and it should come out as the output. So far I have written:

```
def pivot_nested_dict(nested_dict):
5       stateDict={}
6       for i in nested_dict:
7           dict2=nested_dict[i]
8           for j in dict2:
9               stateDict[j]= {i: dict2[j]}
10      return stateDict
11  
12  print pivot_nested_dict(input)
```

I almost have the answer, output={'y': {'a': 2}, 'x': {'b': 3}, 'z': {'b': 4}}.
So, the x key is overwriting the 'a': 1. How do I keep both the a and the b?

Comment: its not clear what you want. I see that you're providing an input->output pair, but it still isn't decipherable what you want. especially because from where i'm sitting it's a near arbitrary permutation.

Comment: the output is just to show what my output should be

Comment: If it's as simple as that, replace the body of your code with `return {'y': {'a': 2}, 'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, 'z': {'b': 4} }`

Comment: the most confusing thing you've done posting this question is input and output formatting with chaotic spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to this is check if the key is already in `stateDict`, if it is, then add a new element to the nested dictionary:

```
def pivot_nested_dict(nested_dict):
    stateDict = {}
    for i in nested_dict:
        dict2 = nested_dict[i]
        for j in dict2:
            if j not in stateDict:
                stateDict[j] = {i: dict2[j]}
            else:
                stateDict[j][i] = dict2[j]
    return stateDict

print pivot_nested_dict(inp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short of duplicating the dictionary, there is no way to retain the original value on a dictionary once you change the value that corresponds to the given key.

For example, the below overwriting will always happen no matter how complex the data structure.

```
x = {'a':1}
x['a'] = 2
print x
>>> {'a': 2}
```

You can duplicate it, but the original value will need to be managed manually.

```
x = {'a':1}
x,oldx = x,x.copy()
oldx['a'] = 2
print x, oldx
>>> {'a': 2} {'a': 1}
```

You could take advantage of the fact that values can be any type of structure including arrays or dictionaries, to store each successive change of value.

Comment: Have you tried your second block of code?  `x, oldx = x, x` just creates two references to your original `x`.  `x is oldx` returns `True` after that line.  Perhaps you should take the more traditional approach:  `oldx = x.copy()`

Comment: @mgilson Whoops, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I ve got this little script yo get your job done.
**NOTE**: Provided the input is correct.

**code:**

```
output = {}
for d in input.items():
    for item in d:
        if type(item) == dict:
            for i in item.keys():
                d = {k:item[i]}
                output[i] = {k:item[i]} if not i in output.keys() else dict(output[i].items() + d.items())
        else: k=item
```

**input:**

```
input = { "a" : { "x": 1, "y": 2 ,'z':15},"b" : { "x": 3, "z": 4 } }
```

**output:**

```
{'y': {'a': 2}, 'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, 'z': {'a': 15, 'b': 4}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this one

```
input = { "a" : { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
     "b" : { "x": 3, "z": 4 } }

output = {}

for k,v in zip(input.keys(), input.values()):
    for kk, vv in zip(v.keys(), v.values()):
        if kk in output.keys():
            output[kk][k] = vv
        else:
            output[kk] = {k : vv}
```